# How to a pass a complex object as a mock data service stub

Tags: testing, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm working on a test for a module, which works except for the fact that I can not access, the inner object `attributes` properties.

```js
tokenStorageServiceStub = { // Mock service data
    getUser: () => of({
        username: 'organization-a-a-normal',
        roles: ['PROCESSOR'],
        attributes: {
            organizationId: 111,
            organizationName: 'Org.name Aa',
            userFullName: 'User for organization A-A',
            userId: 22,
        },
        access_token: 'AT01',
        refresh_token: 'RT01',
        token_type: 'Bearer',
        expires_in: 3600,
    }),
};
```

The component code complains about the last statement:

```js
this.activeTokens = this.token.getUser(); // OK
this.username = this.activeTokens.username; // OK
this.organization.id = this.activeTokens.attributes.organizationId; // `attributes` is undefined?
```

> Chrome Headless 88.0.4298.0 (Linux x86_64) SettingsComponent should create FAILED
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'organizationId' of undefined
> at SettingsComponent.call [as ngOnInit] (src/app/organization/settings/settings.component.ts:22:61)

I think it's because of the innerworking of the *RxJs.of()* function. In the manual, I see things like ObservableInput. But there is no mention of Objects as such.

I also read about `of()` getting deprecated? What will be a good approach to pass my object data in a test service stub?

Comment: `getUser` returns an Observable. Please read about testing async functions.

Comment: Yes, `getUser` returns an Observable, and this works. Except, property _attributes_ (also provided with data) is undefined. Can not access _organizationId_ while username is accessible.